# Arquillian TomEE tests performance

Tags: java, maven, jboss-arquillian, apache-tomee, openejb

I'm using Arquillian and TomEE embedded adapter to test a WAR.
In my `pom.xml` I have the following entry

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-tomee-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and in my `arquillian.xml` I have the following

```
<container qualifier="tomee" default="true">
    <configuration>
        [...]
        <property name="javaVmArguments">-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m</property>
        <property name="singleDumpByArchiveName">true</property>
        <!--<property name="singleDeploymentByArchiveName">true</property>-->
        [...]
    </configuration>
</container>
```

Adding the property `singleDumpByArchiveName` I expected that, dumping only once the web archive for all the tests, there would be an improvement in terms of execution time, but that did not happen.

I also tried to add the Arquillian Suite Extension with the same goal

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eu.ingwar.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-suite-extension</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

but I get the following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestResult.setEnd(J)V
```

Do you have any tip on how to make these solutions work or can you suggest others to speed up the tests execution time?

Answer (score 0):

first of all:

```
<property name="javaVmArguments">-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m</property>
```

is not a tomee configuration since tomee embedded doesn't fork a JVM, probably something copied/pasted from the net.

Then your error probably just means you have a dependency conflict (tomee brings an older version of arquillian). You need to fix that. You can need to use tomee 1.7.4 (or 7.x) which is compatible with arquillian > 1.1.11